# Logout from firebase app at Java end

Tags: java, android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app that supports IOS and Andriod. The login is based on Firebase authentication and logout is done at the app end.

Now I would like to implement the logout functionality at the backend, where I would built a REST API. I would like to logout from the Firebase in this API such that when App calls this API, user gets logged out. Below is the API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/logout/{userId}", method = POST)
public Response<User> logout(Long userId) {
    //Want to logout with a firebase call
 }
```

I am trying to built an API which logout user from the App. Currently the logout is handled at App end. I would like to handle this at the backed using Java. Handling at the Java end allows me to keep track some parameters when user logs out.

I have searched inside the Firebase documentation which was available for only Andriod and IOS but was not able to find any method to logout from firebase to handle from backend(not from App). Does firebase supports logout from backend?

Comment: What does it mean for you to "logout from backend"?  What are you trying to do that you can't do in your mobile app?

Comment: Yes, actually it is logout call to backend API. I am trying to built an API which logout user from the App. Currently the logout is handled at App end. I would like to handle this at the backed using Java

Comment: All sign-in information from Firebase Authentication is kept on the client. There is no back-end to sign out of. The only way to sign a client out is to throw away their token, which you do by calling signout from the client.

Comment: So I there anyway I can maintain signout at back-end. I would like to built some parameters when user logs out. Can the client send any parameters when user logsout.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Can I use firebase simple login plugin. I think it provides us the leverage to signout at the backend

Comment: Maybe you can use the Firebase Remote Config for this. You can also make use of a notification/push service from Firebase.

Comment: As I said: the only way to sign a client out is to throw away their token, which you do by calling a sign-out method from the client

Comment: thanks your confirmation helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented:

Saving "idToken" and "refreshToken" into the client (Mobile App) with a flag "isAuthenticated".

When a user login I set in Redux an object {idToken: USER_ID_TOKEN, refreshToken: USER_REFRESH_TOKEN, isAuthentitated: **true**}

When user logOut I update my object {idToken: USER_ID_TOKEN, refreshToken: USER_REFRESH_TOKEN, isAuthentitated: **false**}

Finally whe you need to know if user is authenticated you verify the flag **isAuthenticated** from Redux

For each request from App to backend, I send "refreshToken" for verifying user and when Firebase sendback response to backend with the new "idToken" and "refreshToken", I forward this information to App in order to update Redux.

You can find Redux implementation on following page: https://alligator.io/react/react-native-redux/